# VLC Firefox plugin won't stream .ts like Windows VLC will

Tags: firefox, video, vlc, nginx, streaming

I have an nginx sever that just lists the files in a directory where I keep .ts files. Under Firefox on Windows, the VLC plugin will start streaming the .ts file when I click on it.

Under Ubuntu, with the latest Firefox and installing browser-plugin-vlc, .ts files will not stream. It wants to save the file to disk.

How can I have Firefox stream the .ts file in Ubuntu?

EDIT: Here is the dpkg -l output and Firefox plugins. This is using Firefox 48 (latest at the time) and no plugin updates when i checked with the cog wheel:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAn4O.png

VLC on Ubuntu version: VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)

VLC on Windows 10 version: VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax

Comment: Is VLC listed **and** enabled in Firefox under plugins? Which Version of VLC are you using on Windows and which one under Ubuntu?

Comment: Also make sure the package `browser-plugin-vlc` is installed. From a terminal window you can check this by typing in `dpkg -l browser-plugin-vlc`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package `browser-plugin-vlc` is installed. From a terminal window you can check this by typing in `dpkg -l browser-plugin-vlc`.

You can install it by `sudo apt install browser-plugin-vlc` - don't forget to restart Firefox after installing it. Then check if it gets listed in Firefox under `Add-ons`/`Plugins` and if it is enabled.

Comment: I've updated the main post with your suggestions. Hopefully this will help!